# Stokes Theorem. Where is my mistake?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Use Stoke's Theorem to prove that the following line integral has the indicated value. $$ \int_\mathscr{C} y \,dx +z\,dy+x\,dz = \pi a^2 \sqrt{3}$$ where $\mathscr{C}$ is the intersection curve $\mathscr{C}: \begin{cases} x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2 \\ x+y+z=0 \end{cases}$

This is what I did.
$$ \mathbf{I} = \int_\mathscr{C} y \,dx +z\,dy+x\,dz = \int_\mathscr{C} \mathbf{F}(x,y,z) \cdot d\mathbf{\overrightarrow{r}} \qquad \text{where} \,\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)=(y,z,x)$$

Then, by the Stoke's theorem $$ \mathbf{I} =\iint_S(\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{S}= \iint_S (-1,-1,-1) \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{S} $$
I choose $S$ as the plane that contains $\mathscr{C}$.

$$ \mathbb{\alpha}(x,y)=(x,y,-x-y) \qquad(x,y)\in T \\ $$ In cylindrical coordinates $$ \mathbb{\alpha}(r,\theta)=\left( rcos\theta,rsin\theta,-r(cos\theta+ sin\theta)\right) \qquad (r,\theta)\in [0,a]\times[0,2\pi]=T^* \\ 
N= \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial r} \times \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial\theta}=(r,r,r)$$

Therefore
$$ \mathbf{I}= \iint_{T^*} (-1,-1,-1) \cdot (r,r,r) \mathrm{d}A = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^a -3r \, \mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta = -3a^2\pi$$
Unfortunately, I can't find where is my mistake. Can you help me, please?

Comment: You've parametrized $S$ incorrectly. The condition on $x$ and $y$ is $x^2 + y^2 + (x + y)^2 = a^2$.

Comment: That was the hardest step for me. Can you help me with that?

Comment: No need to go so hard with parameterizations. The surface is a disc in the plane. The *normalized* normal $N=(1,1,1)/\sqrt{3}$, $dA=r\,dr\,d\theta$ (note extra $r$ from Jacobian after change to the (plane) polar coordinates). Negative sign depends on the orientation of the curve (not given, so may answer with minus).

Comment: I know, but I don't get how to parametrize a disc with inclination.

Comment: Is the integral correct, or is it supposed to be $$\int_{\mathscr{C}}y\,\mathrm{d}x+z\,\mathrm{d}y+x\,\mathrm{d}\color{#C00000}{z}$$ which matches the dot product mentioned in the question?

Comment: You are right. That was a typo error, thanks. Editing.

Answer (score 2):

Since the plane passes through the origin, the curve of intersection is a circle of radius $a$ and so we may take our surface to be a disk of radius $a$. (Note that Stokes' Theorem allows you to take $\textit {any}$ surface whose boundary is the curve over which the line integral is to be taken. We choose the disk because it is the easiest).

Now, observe that you can read off a vector normal to the disk because it is part of the plane $x+y+z=0$; namely, $(1,1,1)$ (choosing one of two possible normals).

So your integral is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\int \int _{S}(\vec \nabla \times \vec F)\cdot (1,1,1)dS=\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\int \int _{S}(-1,-1,-1)\cdot (1,1,1)dS=-\frac{3}{\sqrt 3}\int \int _{S}dS$$ But this last integral just computes the surface area of what we have determined is a disk of radius $a$, so we get $-\frac{3\pi a^{2}}{\sqrt 3}$ and so there was no need here to worry about parameterizations! And this is probably the point of the exercise. Trying to find a suitable parameterization is a real chore.

Comment: I don't understand why the coefficient $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ appears.

Comment: @André: I normalized $(1,1,1)$ as required.

Comment: Yes. What I don't understand is why you need a normalized vector instead any vector perpendicular to the surface...

Comment: I'm starting to feel that I need more worked examples or a more detailed textbook. Can you recommend some books, please?**@a@

Comment: @André: before doing stokes' thm, look at how surface integrals in general are developed. Then when you get to ST. you will see how the normal vector enters in normalized form. I like Susan Colley's book: Vector Calculus (3rd Edition)

Answer (score 2):

One parametrization of $\mathscr{C}$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\vphantom{\frac1{\sqrt2}}\\y\vphantom{\frac1{\sqrt2}}\\z\vphantom{\frac1{\sqrt2}}\end{bmatrix}
=a\cos(\theta)\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}\\\lower{2pt}{0}\vphantom{\frac1{\sqrt2}}\\-\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{bmatrix}
+a\sin(\theta)\begin{bmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt6}\\-\frac2{\sqrt6}\\\frac1{\sqrt6}\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$

---

However, using Stokes Theorem, we get the integral to be
$$
\int_{\mathscr{C}}y\,\mathrm{d}x+z\,\mathrm{d}y+x\,\mathrm{d}z=\iint_{\mathscr{S}}\underbrace{\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x+\,\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}y+\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z}_{(1,1,1)\,\cdot\,n\,\mathrm{d}\sigma}\tag{2}
$$
where $\mathscr{S}$ is the intersection surface $\mathscr{S}:\left\{\begin{array}{l} x^2+y^2+z^2\le a^2\\ x+y+z=0 \end{array}\right.$

Since the unit normal to $\mathscr{S}$ is $\left(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)$, the integral on the right side of $(2)$ equals the area of $\mathscr{S}$ times $\left(\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3},\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)\cdot(1,1,1)=\sqrt3$. That is, the integral is
$$
\underbrace{\pi a^2}_{\substack{\text{area}\\\text{of $\mathscr{S}$}}}\sqrt3\tag{3}
$$

Comment: I don't get why you take the unit normal vector. Aren't  the surface integrals over vector fields independent of the parametrization? (with, at most, a different sign).

Comment: I mean... if I take another parametrization of the disk, the direction of the normal vector must be the same, but the norm does not, right? Why in this case the result depends of what parametrization I choose?

Comment: @André Once you pick axis units, your area units are fixed, they do not depend on parameterizations. When you choose a parameterization it may have another units, so the length of the normal vector (when you take the vector product of tangent vectors) takes care for the unit conversion itself (like Jacobian does). Since here we do not take any particular parameterization, we need the normal vector to be of **lengh one** in order to keep the area scale on the disc unchanged.

Comment: @André: Think of it this way: $\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x =(0,0,1)\cdot n\,\mathrm{d}\sigma$, where $\mathrm{d}\sigma$is the area of the intersection of $\mathscr{S}$ with the infinite rectangular prism $$[x,x+\mathrm{d}x] \times[y,y+\mathrm{d}y] \times[-\infty,+\infty]$$ Once you see that, do the same thing for $\mathrm{d}z\,\mathrm{d}y =(1,0,0)\cdot n\,\mathrm{d}\sigma$ and $\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z =(0,1,0)\cdot n\,\mathrm{d}\sigma$ where $\mathrm{d}\sigma$ is the area of intersection of $\mathscr{S}$ with the infinite rectangular prism in the appropriate direction.